# changing array keys in array_walk function?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I am using array functions to convert my pipe delimited string to an associative array.

```
$piper = "|k=f|p=t|e=r|t=m|";

$piper = explode("|",$piper);

$piper = array_filter($piper);

function splitter(&$value,$key) {

    $splitted = explode("=",$value);
    $key = $splitted[0];
    $value = $splitted[1];

}

array_walk($piper, 'splitter');

var_dump($piper);
```

this gives me

```
array (size=4)
  1 => string 'f' (length=1)
  2 => string 't' (length=1)
  3 => string 'r' (length=1)
  4 => string 'm' (length=1)
```

where i want:

```
array (size=4)
  "k" => string 'f' (length=1)
  "p" => string 't' (length=1)
  "e" => string 'r' (length=1)
  "t" => string 'm' (length=1)
```

but the keys are unaltered. Is there any array function with which i can loop over an array and change keys and values as well?

Comment: What's the desired resulting array?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: i have updated it

Comment: The edit: "Which is fastest" makes this now a not constructive question in my eyes. See my comment below.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It's said in the documentation of [**array_walk**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) (describing the callback function):

> Only the values of the array may potentially be changed; its structure
>   cannot be altered, i.e., the programmer cannot add, unset or reorder
>   elements. If the callback does not respect this requirement, the
>   behavior of this function is undefined, and unpredictable.

That means you cannot use `array_walk` to alter the keys of iterated array. You can, however, create a new array with it:

```
$result = array();
array_walk($piper, function (&$value,$key) use (&$result) {
    $splitted = explode("=",$value);
    $result[ $splitted[0] ] = $splitted[1];
});
var_dump($result);
```

---

Still, I think if it were me, I'd use regex here (instead of "exploding the exploded"):

```
$piper = "|k=f|p=t|e=r|t=m|";
preg_match_all('#([^=|]*)=([^|]*)#', $piper, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$piper = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
var_dump($piper);
```

Comment: Well, this is overhead compared to a simple foreach iteration which already contains the code and there is no need to pass variables across scopes.

Comment: why would you use array_walk and not a simple foreach for this purpose?

Comment: please suggest me which one will execute fastest? foreach or the regex or is it the array_walk?

Comment: @mithunsatheesh: i think the regex solution is the slowest. i'm not sure between foreach and array_walk. maybe someone else can chip in.

Comment: Because the question was about "array function", and I wanted to show how it's possible to do with that. I do agree that `foreach` approach is more clean here; it's more important, though, that you still have to create a separate array to store the results. And I've shown the approach that I'd choose here: for me, it's better than foreaching explodes (in fact, I'd try first to reorganize the input for `parse_str` to be usable, but that's probably another story).

Comment: @AlexandruMihai And why exactly regex solution should be the slowest here, may I ask? Just because it's 'usually' slowest?

Comment: @raina77ow: yes, because applying a regex is usually more time consuming. since neither you nor I took the time to test this particular case, I'd bet the regex solution is slower.

Comment: @AlexandruMihai You miss the fact that 'explode' would be called as many times as there are 'k=v' tokens here, making it more expensive than single `preg_match_all` call. And "usually" is a terrible word to be used in optimization discussions.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh: according to this article http://willem.stuursma.name/2010/11/22/a-detailed-look-into-array_map-and-foreach/ , foreach is faster than array_map, so I'd say it's also faster than array_walk given the functional similarities between array_walk and array_map.

Comment: @AlexandruMihai: thanks bro.. i have been following your comments.. provided my string has too many pipe delimited values, which one will you choose ? explode or preg_match_all? rest is clear.

Comment: @raina77ow: i had this already done with foreach way. you have done the rest two ways that i tried but couldnt get working.. thanks.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh: no problem. personally I'd go with the explode approach for readability. i also believe it's faster.

Comment: thanks. I was wondering why I cannot return the `$result` and use it outside the `array_walk`. I found the answer in your code, mine is missing the`&` symbol.

Answer (score 2):

You can better use `foreach` for that. The following example shows processing an entry, adding it with the right key and deleting the original entry.

```
$piper = "|k=f|p=t|e=r|t=m|";
$piper = array_filter(explode("|", $piper));

foreach ($piper as $index => $value) {
    list($key, $value) = explode("=", $value);
    $piper[$key] = $value;
    unset($piper[$index]);
}
```

Take care you do not have keys that are like an index.

Another alternative is to process the values via a reference and set the keys afterwards:

```
foreach ($piper as &$value) {
    list($keys[], $value) = explode("=", $value);
}
unset($value);

$piper = array_combine($keys, $piper);
```

This does not bring you into any troubles but just with duplicate keys. But you could check for that problem after the `foreach`, no data would be lost.

Something that can not be guaranteed with the following `foreach` which probably is the most simplified by stroing into a result array:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($piper as $value) {
    list($key, $value) = explode("=", $value);
    $result[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: I added a second example which re-uses the value which is more fitting. In any case  `$piper` is for processing so I don't see any problem to use (not re-use) it.

Comment: please suggest me which one will execute fastest? foreach or the regex or is it the array_walk?

Comment: I would go with the `foreach` because it is more straight forward and clear what it does. For all answers you must not need to care which is fastest, all are fast enough in your case. If you care about speed, you need to metric for your case(s) if it's really the fractions of milliseconds that count.

Comment: @hakre I wish I could take this comment into my answer-thread as well. )

Answer (score 2):

Why not build a new array that has the desired keys and values from $piper?

```
$piper2 = array();
foreach ($piper as $k => $val)
{
  $splitted = explode("=", $val);
  $key = $splitted[0];
  $value = $splitted[1];

  $piper2[$key] = $value;
}

$piper = $piper2; // if needed
```

Comment: please suggest me which one will execute fastest? foreach or the regex or is it the array_walk?

Answer (score 2):

Using array_reduce will do the trick

```
$piper = "|k=f|p=t|e=r|t=m|";

$piper = explode("|",$piper);

$piper = array_filter($piper);

function splitter($result, $item) {
    $splitted = explode("=",$item);
    $key = $splitted[0];
    $value = $splitted[1];

    $result[$key] = $value;

    return $result;
}

$piper = array_reduce($piper, 'splitter', array());

var_dump($piper);
```

based on this: http://www.danielauener.com/howto-use-array_map-on-associative-arrays-to-change-values-and-keys/

Answer (score 0):

This my recursive function that can change not only the values of the array as array_walk_recursive() **but also the keys** of the given array. It also keeps the order of the array:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57622225/10452175