# PHP - each value of the associative array derived from value of indexed array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this: `['.1', '.2', '1.1', '2.0']` (but it has more values).

In PHP, is there a function that will allow me to pass an **indexed array as an argument and return an associative array where the keys of the associative array are the values of the original array, and each value of the associative array is derived from its key** (such as by a formatting function)?

I imagine that I'll be able to pass an anonymous callback function as an argument to translate the value of the indexed array into the new value of the associative array.

In my case, I'm hoping to receive:

`['.1' => '10%', '.2' => '20%', '1.1' => '110%', '2.0' => '200%']`

(This associative array will then be used in `Form::select()` in a Laravel view.)

I have spent a long time researching [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php), [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php), and others, but I haven't figured it out.

Comment: Sorry, but float keys are not allowed in arrays.

Comment: @u_mulder, Thanks, I fixed the keys. The core idea of my question still remains. Please see my question now that I've fixed the keys. Thanks!

Comment: you can use those `array_walk` but you have to use the `use` part of the closure.  see this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271015/changing-array-keys-in-array-walk-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments you can use array walk

```
$result = array();
$array = [0.1, 0.2, 1.1, 2.0, 2.5];

array_walk($array, function (&$value) use (&$result) {
     $result[(string)$value] = ($value * 100) . '%';
});
var_dump($result);
```

Outputs

```
array(5) {
  ["0.1"]=> string(3) "10%"
  ["0.2"]=> string(3) "20%"
  ["1.1"]=> string(4) "110%"
  [2]=> string(4) "200%" /// <-- int
  ["2.5"]=>  string(4) "250%"
}
```

What's odd/interesting is I just noticed 2 is not a string.  Anyway, if they need one decimal ( and only have one ) place you can use this version with `number_format` instead.

```
$result = array();
$array = [0.1, 0.2, 1.1, 2.0, 2.5];

array_walk($array, function (&$value) use (&$result) {
     $result[number_format($value,1)] = ($value * 100) . '%';
});
var_dump($result);
```

Outputs

```
array(5) {
  ["0.1"]=>
  string(3) "10%"
  ["0.2"]=>
  string(3) "20%"
  ["1.1"]=>
  string(4) "110%"
  ["2.0"]=>
  string(4) "200%"
  ["2.5"]=>
  string(4) "250%"
}
```

if there is more decimal places or they are variable you could count the digits after the decimal, and use that as the second input into `number_format` I can think of at least 2 ways to do that.

You can test them here

**First:**

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/30ec8bdc191095ac92a681b3f8fc964c66360c86

**Second:**

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e02d45e6d02e79a2440110b7ffe6df93e76920d3

I was just thinking about the decimal thing, if you want to insure they have at least one decimal, but some could have more then you can do it this way.

```
array_walk($array, function (&$value) use (&$result) {
     $key = (string)$value;
     if(strlen($key) == 1 ) 
        $key = number_format($key, 1);

     $result[$key] = ($value * 100) . '%';
});
```

This also might make it a few fractions of a microsecond faster, because you avoid calling `number_format` on the ones that can simply be converted to the string representation of a float "2.1".  However, even that will trim off trailing 0's when there is more then one decimal place "1.10" becomes "1.1" but at least it keeps them all floats.

You can see this one here

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e836076f7ee6c2e684d4ccca016101b288649f29

Note I modified a few of the values, such as "1.101" and "1.10" to illustrate this.

Comment: Because it can be simple converted to `2`

Comment: yea I realize that.  Still if I say `(string)` I shouldn't get an int.

Comment: I should clearly that, I understand whey it turns `2.0` into `2` but it should have still cast it to a string, no?  `"2"` instead of `2`

Comment: Super helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Sure glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Simple example with [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/array_reduce):

```
$a = [0.1, 0.2, 1.1, 2.0, 2.5];
$new_a = array_reduce(
    $a,
    function ($t, $v) { $t[(string)$v] = (100 * $v) . '%'; return $t; },
    []
);
echo'<pre>',print_r($new_a),'</pre>';
```