# Using mysql_real_escape_string in a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am working on a big script which will generate some **string** or **array**  or **multidimensional array** i want use **`mysql_real_escape_string`** for all array / string
for that this i tried the below code

```
function check($data) {
    if(!is_array($data)) {
        return mysql_real_escape_string($data);
    } else if (is_array($data)) {
       $newData = array();
       foreach($data as $dataKey => $dataValue){
             if(!is_array($dataValue)){
                 $key = mysql_real_escape_string($dataKey);
                 $value = mysql_real_escape_string($dataValue);
                 $newData[$key] = $value;
             }
        }
        return $newData;
     }  
}
```

if i use like this `check('saveme');` this returns value

if i pass a array it returns corrent value [ `check(array('a','b','c',1,2,3))` ]

if i pass multidimensional array i get [`check(array(array('a',array('a','b','c',1,2,3),'c',1,2,3),'b',array('a','b','c',1,2,3),1,2,3))`]

A kind note i want to use mysql_real_escape_string for array key too.

Comment: What is purpose of this function?

Comment: make recursive function

Comment: _(makes an Obi-Wan gesture)_ you don't need this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net//manual/ru/function.array-walk-recursive.php) function, to go throw all leaves of the array, and escape values:

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$leaf) {
    if (is_string($leaf))
       $leaf = mysql_real_escape_string($leaf);
});
```

Also, it is good to follow data consistency rules, and do not use `!is_array()`, but `is_string()`, because `mysql_real_escape_string` takes `string` params, not `!string`.

Unfortunately, `array_walk_recursive` is designed so, that it can't edit `keys`. If you need edit keys, you may want to write your own recursive function. I don't want to copy answer, you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7491283/2180005)

Comment: @S.Varun do you need only values, or v&k?

Comment: @wingofovnia so its not possible right. its possible by custom function

Comment: @S.Varun yep. follow the link I've specified. There is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function :

(**MyStringEscapeFunc()** is your custom escape function)

```
function escape_recursive($arr){
    if(is_array($arr)){
        $temp_arr = array();
        foreach ($arr as $key=>$value){
                $temp_arr[MyStringEscapeFunc($key)] = escape_recursive($value);
        }
        return $temp_arr;
    }else{
        return MyStringEscapeFunc($arr);
    }
}
```

**Example Result :**

```
//Before :
Array (
[0] => Array ( 
          [0] => foo'bar
          [1] => bar'baz
        ) 
[1] => foob'ar
[2] => Array ( [foo'baz] => baz'foo ) 
) 



//After : 
Array ( 
[0] => Array (
        [0] => foo\'bar
        [1] => bar\'baz
       )
[1] => foob\'ar 
[2] => Array ( [foo\'baz] => baz\'foo )
)
```